# Exibir um bloco de texto/fotos carregado dinamicamente com QML para Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

Estou escrevendo um aplicativo utilizando o QML do recem-lançado Qt 5.2 direcionado para Android. Em uma das telas preciso exibir um artigo que é carregado de um servidor e pode sofrer alterações depois do lançamento do aplicativo. O artigo seria basicamente um bloco de texto com imagens e alguma formatação básica (negrito, itálito, fonte maior em títulos de seções, etc). Qual a melhor forma de renderizar esse conteúdo?

O ideal seria escrever em html e embutir em um `WebView`, mas o WebKit não está disponível para o Android. Outra opção seriam escrever o artigo em QML e incluir usando um `Loader`. Mas parece ser complicado por texto com formatação e quebra de linha assim. Uma última forma seria criar uma classe em C++ que exponha uma interface ao QML e que tenha sua própria mecânica de renderização. Assim seria possível usar um `QTextDocument` e jogar em um `QPainter`.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso? Quais os problemas com as formas que pensei?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução enquanto navegava pela documentação. O elemento `Text` [suporta mais do que apenas texto](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#textFormat-prop), ele também pode exibir um [subconjunto do HTML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), incluindo imagem e toda a formatação necessária. Um exemplo:

```qml
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 360
    height: 360
    Text {
        x: 15
        width: parent.width-30
        textFormat: Text.StyledText
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        text: "<h1>Teste</h1>" +
              "Teste de um <b>parágrafo</b> qualquer.<br>" +
              "<img src='qmltest80.png'></img><br>" +
              "Mais <i>texto</i> aqui."
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image]